# Trying to get Excel Autofill to raise value in one reference and stay on the same in the other

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I having some issues creating a pricelist where I'm using `=FIND` to convert a discount class into actual discount using 3 tables.

1. First table is raw data (including the discount class)
2. Second table is my discount matrix, one column has the discount class and the other the actual discount.
3. Third table is where I'm presenting the data.

And the formula I have now works great but I need to autofill about `100000` rows so I really can't stand modifying the code manually.

My code as I would like it to fill is below, pay attention to the `Nx` ref and `Cx:Cx` ref:

`=FIND('Prislista 60 SZ MC_MOP_ATV 1305'!N2;'Rab kod'!B1:B32;'Rab kod'!C1:C32)`
`=FIND('Prislista 60 SZ MC_MOP_ATV 1305'!N3;'Rab kod'!B1:B32;'Rab kod'!C1:C32)`
`=FIND('Prislista 60 SZ MC_MOP_ATV 1305'!N4;'Rab kod'!B1:B32;'Rab kod'!C1:C32)`

And How Excel actually does:

`=FIND('Prislista 60 SZ MC_MOP_ATV 1305'!N2;'Rab kod'!B1:B32;'Rab kod'!C1:C32)`
`=FIND('Prislista 60 SZ MC_MOP_ATV 1305'!N3;'Rab kod'!B1:B32;'Rab kod'!C2:C33)`
`=FIND('Prislista 60 SZ MC_MOP_ATV 1305'!N4;'Rab kod'!B1:B32;'Rab kod'!C3:C34)`

Anyone having an idea how to get this to work? or maybe i can use anther function to do the same thing. I have thought about using the =IF but the there will be a long writeup and changes in discount classes will take a lot of effort.

Comment: Try this `=FIND('Prislista 60 SZ MC_MOP_ATV 1305'!N2;'Rab kod'!B1:B32;'Rab kod'!$C$1:$C$32)` Notice the `$`

Comment: Explanation: `$` will make the range `Constant` so whichever direction you move the formula, the range will remain constant. Put the above formula in the 1st Cell and then do an autofill :)

Comment: Is it a typo or should the `B1:B32` range also change in your 'how excel actually does'?

Comment: Perfect, worked great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems:

```
=VTSÖK('Prislista 60 SZ MC_MOP_ATV 1305'!N2;'Rab kod'!B:C;2;0)
```

was suitable. (VTSÖK is the Swedish for VLOOKUP.)